# RemoteCertificateNameMismatch when auth using SslStream on linux

Tags: linux, ssl, tcp, .net-core

I've come across some strange behaviour of dotnet SslStream, when running my dotnet-core app on linux environment.

here is the code:

```
TcpClient cl = new TcpClient();
cl.Connect("52.209.63.190", 443);
var ssl = new SslStream(cl.GetStream());
ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("api.bitfinex.com");
```

Auth result is success, when running on windows.
But same code ends with auth error (RemoteCertificateNameMismatch), when linux.

dotnet --info:

.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.4)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.1.4
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  5e8add2190

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     fedora
 OS Version:  27
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.4/

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

Version  : 2.0.5
  Build    : 17373eb129b3b05aa18ece963f8795d65ef8ea54

Why code behaviour is so different on linux? 
How can I handle it and pass ssl auth?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please test it by this way cl.Connect("api.bitfinex.com", 443);

Comment: it works, but dns is resolved with different ip which I don't want to connect to.

Comment: I don't know how you get the IP address of api.bitfinex.com, but api.bitfinex.com is under cloudflare, and that domain resolves with cloudflare.

Comment: it is not about cloudflare or specific host and ip, it is about app behaviour on different platforms

Comment: .NET Core uses Win32 API on Windows to implement SSL, while on Linux it currently uses openssl. Thus, the behavior can slightly differ. There is nothing to be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can connect to that host with

```
TcpClient cl = new TcpClient();
cl.Connect("api.bitfinex.com", 443);
var ssl = new SslStream(cl.GetStream());
ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("api.bitfinex.com");
```

I don't know how you got the IP address of api.bitfinex.com, but it's under cloudflare, and may be you don't need to connect bitfinex with his real IP address.

But if it is required to connect that special IP address, you can override verification callback before you do any connection

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

Comment: I don't need to override verification callback on windows. Why?
I can reach the host by this IP using default linux tools (like curl or wscat) easily.
Simple C++ example written in the same manner also passes authentication.
So it looks like dotnet and linux specific issue

Comment: I've just tried to run you'r code on my Linux Environment,  and it's worked without any RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

Comment: I've updated dotnet --info in my question.
what linux and dotnet do You use?

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux, with dotnet 2.1.300 version

Comment: Hm.. I'll try testing different linux environments. thanks

Comment: Keep us posted. Thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is simple: too old dotnet version.

2.0 seems to have some ssl issues, which were fixed since 2.1

When I installed the newest one (2.1.3), my app still didn't work, decause I had to uninstall prev version (2.0.5) manually to be able to use 2.1.3

Now the app ends with the same result on both windows and linux environments.

Many thanks to M. Hovhannisyan. I've started trying different linux versions, and figured out what I did wrong